# cannot get cdata result using xstream, stax2, woodstox

Tags: java, xml, xstream, stax, woodstox

sample xml

```
<root>
  <first>
    <second><![CDATA[hello, world]]></second>
  </first>
<root>
```

I'm using xstream(1.4.7), stax2-api(3.1.4), woodstox(5.0.3).

```
@Test
    public void xmlInputFactoryTest() throws XMLStreamException, IOException {

        ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("/sample/input.xml");

        NameCoder nameCoder = new XmlFriendlyNameCoder();

        XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        XMLEventReader reader = factory.createXMLEventReader(resource.getInputStream());
        XMLStreamReader streamReader = StaxUtils.createEventStreamReader(reader);
        HierarchicalStreamReader hsr = new StaxReader(new QNameMap(), streamReader, nameCoder);
        write(hsr);
    }

    public void write(HierarchicalStreamReader hsr) {
        System.out.println(hsr.getNodeName() + ", " + hsr.getValue()); // should be print "hello,world" in second tag
        if (hsr.hasMoreChildren()) {
            hsr.moveDown();
            write(hsr);
        }
    }
```

here is my sample test code

I can not get cdata string result in path "root/first/second"

I think XMLInputFactory.newInstance() return class affect to result.

when I add

```
factory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_COALESCING, true);
```

this code after get XMLInputFactory.newInstance().

It works.
but it does not seem to be the answer.

.

Is not version compatible?

Is there any other way possible?

Comment: What's your issue with setting IS_COALESCING? Seems to be the right thing to do if you only want one event for all the characters?

Comment: When I set up codes xstream, without stax2 and woodstox, It works fine without any setting.
I doubt xstream's compatibility with stax2 or woodstox, but I do not know the exact reason.